# How to use Entity Framework in MySql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, entity-framework

How can I use **Entity Framework** in **Mysql** using **C#-ASP.Net**?

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework

I am trying this tutorial, but I cannot find the **MySql.dll (Win apps), MySql.Data.Entity.dll** in the **Reference**, so I cannot proceed to the next step of that tutorial.

I can't even find Mysql.dll and mysql.data.entity.dll in my Mysql folder, but I already installed mysql in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says "Download and install MySQL Connector" in the  "Prerequisites".

After a quick google the first result was http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/. Following through I found http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/#downloads.

Is this what you were looking for?